# Few FB user unable to get all friend list using facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook graph api(php) in our app. After user login in facebook using my app then some user getting all facebook friend list and few user not getting.

Please suggest.

Comment: With API v2, you will not get _all_ friends of a user any more, but only those that are users of the app as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since v2.0 of the API, you can only get friends who authorized your APP too. You can NOT get ALL friends - unless you need them for tagging or inviting. Although, inviting is only possible for Game Apps with a Canvas implementation.
You only get all friends with a v1.0 App created before end of April 2014. If you get all friends with any other App, report it as a bug.

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)